# assign user as admin in rails through rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to assign parent as superadmin. when i run the command parent.toggle!(superadmin) it doesnt assign the parent as superadmin.

I am not able to locate the error

```
irb(main):004:0> parent.toggle!(:superadmin)
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  Parent Update (0.6ms)  UPDATE "parents" SET "updated_at" = ?, "superadmin" = ? WHERE "parents"."id" = ?  [["updated_at", "2018-06-20 17:50:31.273816"], ["superadmin", 1], ["id", 1]]
  Parent Update (0.2ms)  UPDATE "parents" SET "updated_at" = ?, "superadmin" = ? WHERE "parents"."id" = ?  [["updated_at", "2018-06-20 17:50:31.280343"], ["superadmin", 0], ["id", 1]]
   (1.8ms)  commit transaction
=> true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that the transaction is beign done, remember that toggle doesn't assign true, it changes the false to true a viceversa, depending on the current value that it has.

on the example you are sending, it's changed to true at first but then again to false. you are doing it right talking about code. but maybe there is a callback that changes again the value to false before saving it. Check on your model if there are callbacks or if you have some rules for this.

Comment: NoMethodError (undefined method `toggle_admin' for #<Parent:0x00007fe05328b618>)
Did you mean?  toggle! .. there was some problem in the model. now this the error showing up